# I want to show an image on a url below

Tags: php

I am pretty new to php and I am building up a website on WordPress. It has a page where users will select three option and generate a graphic. This graphic will be then can be shared on facebook and twitter. I have been able to generate and save an image but the problem is that I am unable to show it on URL similar to this website https://democrats.org/my-vote

I am using php GD for generating the image and I have created a php function inside my functions.php. This is my code for image generation.

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('images/border_logo.png');

$im = imagecreate(1700, 800);

$font = '/images/proximanova-sbold.ttf';

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); 

$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 62, 193, 201);

$text_length = 30;

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image

$marge_right = 560;
$marge_bottom = 200;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

$xpos_a = 740; 
$ypos_a = 100; 
$string_a = "I want"; 
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 40, 40, 40);

$xpos_b = 600; 
$ypos_b = 150; 
$string_b = $_POST['favorite'][0].","; 
$sig_b = wordwrap($string_b, $text_length, "<br />", true);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 62, 193, 201);

$xpos_c = 600; 
$ypos_c = 225; 
$string_c = $_POST['favorite'][1].",";
$sig_c = wordwrap($string_c, $text_length, "<br />", true);

$xpos_d = 600; 
$ypos_d = 300; 
$string_d = $_POST['favorite'][2].",";
$sig_d = wordwrap($string_d, $text_length, "<br />", true);

$xpos_e = 620; 
$ypos_e = 380; 
$string_e = 'and that is why I support';

$xpos_f = 700; 
$ypos_f = 420; 
$string_f = 'ABCD';

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the    photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) -  $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

imagettftext($im, 25, 0, $xpos_a , $ypos_a, $black,$font,$string_a); 
$text_b = str_replace('<br />', "\n", $sig_b);
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, $xpos_b, $ypos_b, $blue, $font, $text_b ); 
$text_c = str_replace('<br />', "\n", $sig_c);
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, $xpos_c, $ypos_c, $blue, $font, $text_c); 
$text_d = str_replace('<br />', "\n", $sig_d);
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, $xpos_d, $ypos_d, $blue, $font, $text_d); 
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, $xpos_e, $ypos_e, $black, $font, $string_e); 
imagettftext($im, 25, 0, $xpos_f, $ypos_f, $black, $font, $string_f); 

imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);


$imgFolderPAth = "/images/";
$imagename = date('m-d-Y_hia')."_image.jpg";
// Save the image as 'simpletext.jpg'
$data1 = imagejpeg($im, $imgFolderPAth . $imagename,100);
// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
    $response = array('msg'=>'', 'response'=>'success',      'imgname'=>$imagename);
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}
```

[Sample image](http://myvote.democrats.org/am_grateful_for_teachers_love_obamacare_think_all_americans_are_equal9.html)

Comment: Your question lacks a clear problem statement. You say you are unable to show the image, but you don't mention what you tried.

Comment: You mention you are able to generate and save the image, but not open it via url. I'm guessing you have checked that the image is there and works via FTP or SSH. So, if you can't access it via URL, there is either a permissions problem or the path to the image is not on the public server folders.

Comment: To be very specific, my client wants a feature similar to https://democrats.org/my-vote 

@Sir

Comment: @SirDarius I simply tried using GD library and I was able to create and share that image but the problem is that it is in .jpg format and the quality isn't high. So, I am just looking to find a way about how can I show the graphic generated on a URL. Not as image but just the text a user has selected.

Comment: You could generate a PNG image instead. It is a lossless format.

Comment: I have been able to solve this. The approach I followed was wrong. Instead of generating an image, I simply used javascript to push and $_GET to publish data on a page template. This solves whole logic and now my feature works perfectly. Thanks